# How close to accurate is a HR sensor for calorie burn?

Tags: workout

I have a basic Polar HR sensor. Am in very good shape and do lots of cardio a week. In a 60 minute cardio session I can hardly break 400 calorie burn while my friends boast over 600 burn with a Fitbit and I am in WAY better shape physically than they are. My HR stays within the predetermined range and is average about 153 for about 45 minutes. I have checked and rechecked the data input info for my monitor.  I really just wanted the most simple device I can get for HR, calorie burn etc.  Is it because I do not have a lot of fat to burn and that my heart is in good shape and that I have a fast recovery?  BTW my heart rate drops very fast during a minute rest.  My doctor say my EKG is EXCELLENT!
Should I consider a different device?

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using your device for just what it is meant to measure: Your heart rate (HR) and nothing else.

Such devices are usually very accurate. If you do not thrust your device then you can easily test it by wearing two devices and comparing measurements or by manually counting heartbeats for one minute. Modern devices using green LEDs for sensing colour changes of your skin are considered very reliable.

Even it might have a read out of energy expenditure it is still just measurements of your heart rate converted into another number using some mathematical formulas. Such kind of calculations are subject to many significant errors: They are based on assumptions like energy consumption is related to oxygen transport, and oxygen transport is known from your HR. They will not work if your max HR deviates from the formula 220 minus your age or you are doing anaerobic exercises.

Answer (score 1):

For instance, 1000 steps may equal anything from 40 - 80 kilocalories to lost, based on an individual's weight and height alone.The products don't reveal the calculations (which i think it is continually updated) utilized to figure out calories burned, it really is extremely difficult to find out the precise value.

And also if the calorie counts are not 100% correct, they're comparatively consistent meaning that in case you need to do the actual same task for 2 days consecutively, your calorie burn ought to read as the identical. That is certainly important to enable you to observe how every day's actions impact your calorie burn and evaluate how well you're progressing.

To answer your question whether you should consider a different device, the closest device that you can think about is Wahoo Tickr X (assuming that you used Polar H10), i mean Wahoo is the great rival for Polar, so you can utilize that for any comparison. You can [read here](https://wearvs.com/compare/polar-h10-vs-wahoo-tickr-x) for any comparison or review for both device.